# UITableview not placed correctly in uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UIscrollView that uses a pagecontrol. I'm adding tables to the scrollview in code. The tableviews should have a padding of 20px on each side. So I do the following.

```
 CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
        frame.size.width = 280.0f;
        frame.size.height = self.scrollView.bounds.size.height;

        frame.origin.x = (320 * page)+20;
        NSLog(@"orgin x is %d",(320 * page)+20);
        NSLog(@"orgin x is %f",frame.origin.x);
        frame.origin.y = 0;


        UITableView *tableStage = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        tableStage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(250/255.0) green:(248/255.0) blue:(247/255.0) alpha:100];
        tableStage.delegate = self;
        tableStage.dataSource = self;
        tableStage.tag = page;

        tableStage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:tableStage];
        [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:tableStage];
```

But I'm getting the following result.
[image]

Like you can see the next tableview is always moving something more to the left. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: What does [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:tableStage] do? Replace current table with new table (tableStage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
float offset=20;
frame.size.width = frame.size.width-(2*offset);
frame.origin.x = (320 * page)+offset;
frame.origin.y = 0;
UITableView *tableStage = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
```

and no need for this line

```
    tableStage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: still moving to the left means?

Comment: Yes but I now the problem. The scrollview width was 326 instead of 320. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
frame.size.width = 280.0f;
frame.size.height = self.scrollView.bounds.size.height;
frame.origin.x = (self.scrollView.bounds.size.width * page)+(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width - (frame.size.width/2));
frame.origin.y = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the content size properly and the location of each new table view it will work perfectly.Also enable the paging.